# Get children height out of parent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I used this plugin to make all the div equal on height.

https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows

```
$('.item-container').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
```

My problem is, I want the child div inside of the parent div calculate also.

For example. I want all add to cart button on the bottom same on first two columns. They will get the highest height.The first DETAIL will be the children div to make the add to cart button go down. Can someone help me?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Create a fiddle so that we can help you quickly.

Comment: one css only solution would like to use absolute and relative positions,

Comment: @HassanNisarKhan the first detail is dynamic actually

Comment: yes i know, but it didn't matter.add to cart button will be position absolutely from the bottom let say 10px ..and your equal height plugin will take care of the heights(ie making every div 300px), soo your add to cart button will always be on the same position (int his case 10px above the container block)

Comment: @HassanNisarKhan I get your point but only the image has the height but the rest are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

inside this method: responsiveEqualHeightGrid

write something that will adjust height of bottom child div like:

```
responsiveEqualHeightGrid(){
    var itemContainerHeightThatYouCalculatedBefore; //code of your method that calculate item-container responsive height
    var imageHeight = $('.item-container img').outerHeight;
    var calculateBottomContainerHeightWithAddButton = itemContainerHeightThatYouCalculatedBefore - imageHeight;

    $('.item-container .bottomContainerWithAddButton').outerHeight = calculateBottomContainerHeightWithAddButton;
}
```